# Razor Mediator extra Text tags appearing in HTML

Tags: templating, razormediator

Using an `if` statement while templating using the Razor mediator:

```
@if (...) {
    <text><div></text>
}
@if (...) {
    <text><div></text>
}
@if (...) {
    <text></div></text>
}
```

But while using these `<text>` tags, sometimes extra `</text>` tags will be rendered out for no apparent reason. Any idea why these are being rendered out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the Razor mediator does not test for tag name when attempting to balance tags. I was able to fix this by removing some of the `<text>` tags.

```
@if (...) {
    <div></text>
}
@if (...) {
    <div></text>
}
@if (...) {
    <text></div>
}
```

Additionally, this issue could be avoided altogether by utilizing a different method to render unbalanced tags altogether as mentioned in this post: [How to include partial (unbalanced) html in a Razor Mediator if statement?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12187/how-to-include-partial-unbalanced-html-in-a-razor-mediator-if-statement)